# How to produce author(year) citation in IEEE mode?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, ieeetran

How to produce authoryear-style citation call-outs in IEEE mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please give us a short compilable code we can play with. Do not forget to add two bib entrys to your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "IEEE mode" you mean use of the `IEEEtran` document class, you could achieve your formatting objective by including the following two statements in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
```

---

A simple MWE, to be compiled by running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa, author="Anne Author", title="Thoughts", year=1999}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

\begin{document}
\citet{aa} has argued that \dots
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```